# Phpword: is there a way to use the compatibility word function coming from templating method?

Tags: templating, phpword

Newbie with phpword, I am generating my word.docx using templating with the library phpword but need to remove the compatibility message when opening Word so  I found that but don't know how to use it with TemplateProcessor..

I need to use correctly this method:

```php
$phpWord->getCompatibility()->setOoxmlVersion(15);
```

My code is:

```php
$templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor('phpWord/Template.docx');
$templateProcessor->setValue('txt1', $txt1);
$templateProcessor->saveAs($nameFile);
```

Comment: Code formatting

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: Sorry - I made some changes to the formatting of your question to make it more readable.